# XSL contains against multiple strings

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to alter the existing test if a node contains a certain string. For now it works against one string and it looks like :

```
<xsl:key name="TEST" match="Parrent[contains(./Name,'Aurora') and contains(./Status,'Ongoing')]" use="Final"/>
```

And this later is used to transform the Final value in the node where the Name=Aurora and Status=Ongoing. Now im interested in doing the same but for multiple  values that I get from another .xml file in 15 rows which looks like this:

```
Status
Ongoing
Stoped
Started
Ready
NotReady
.
.
.
```

So basically I would like to do the same as before only for more Status types than Ongoing. What would be the best way to implement such transform ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: **1.** Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- **2.** The exact format of the multiple values list and the method by which you receive it is not clear.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that this is supposed to work in xslT 1.0

Comment: Good. Now whenever you're ready to answer the second question...

Comment: At first I tried to set them in the xsl file within a variable, but I got error since I can't use variables inside xsl:key, at the moment I have them in an external .xml document as mentioned in the post (.xml not .xsl), but I guess I could declare them in other manner since these will be fixed strings, meaning they won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Well do you really need the `contains` check or can you compare for equality? In the latter case you can use the `=` operator with node-sets or sequences of nodes or values e.g. with XSLT 2.0

```
Status = ('Ongoing', 'Stopped', 'Started', 'Ready', 'NotReady')
```

respectively if you have the values in another document with the structure of e.g.

```
<status-list>
  <status>Ongoing</status>
  <status>Stopped</status>
  <status>Started</status>
  ...
</status-list>
```

then you can compare

```
Status = document('status-list-data.xml')/status-list/status
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable in the match attribute of a `<key>`, but you *can* filter the key's results by a predicate. For example, the following expression:

```
key('keyname', something)[Status=exsl:node-set($status-list)/status]
```

will select only nodes that have a child Status whose value is listed in a variable defined as:

```
<xsl:variable name="status-list">
    <status>Ongoing</status>
    <status>Stopped</status>
    <status>Started</status>
    <status>Ready</status>
    <status>NotReady</status>
</xsl:variable>
```

Note that you need to declare the namespace bound to the `exsl` prefix - see:
http://www.exslt.org/exsl/index.html